# How to handle multiple timestamps in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp, format

TS column has both timestamps and I have no clue which timestamp might come

```
08/06/2020 11:52:07 PM  # this is MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss 


07/08/2020 0:31:17  # this is dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Does the `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` timestamp always has the `PM`?

Comment: yes. It always has AM or PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the timestamp with format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` always carries either `PM` or `AM` you could define a parser function like:

```
import pandas as pd

def parse_dt(sdt):
    if 'AM' in sdt or 'PM' in sdt:
        return pd.to_datetime(sdt)
    else:
        return pd.to_datetime(sdt , dayfirst=True)
```

Note, you can also define it using `lambda` for direct use in e.g. `read_csv`

```
lambda dt: pd.to_datetime(sdt) if 'AM' in dt or 'PM' in dt else pd.to_datetime(sdt , dayfirst=True)
```

Testing on your examples gives

```
>>> parse_dt('08/06/2020 11:52:07 PM')
Timestamp('2020-08-06 23:52:07')
>>> parse_dt('07/08/2020 0:31:17')
Timestamp('2020-08-07 00:31:17')
```

Comment: It worked. Now I just need to use apply function on the dataframe .

Comment: @AnimeshKansal, I don't know how your `df` looks like, but you could do something like `df['dt colum'] = df['dt colum'].apply(lambda dt: pd.to_datetime(sdt) if 'AM' in dt or 'PM' in dt else pd.to_datetime(sdt , dayfirst=True))`.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it. Thank you so much Stefan